# Content shared to a Facebook page that I manage is only visible to me

Tags: facebook

I am trying to share content from a website that I own to my Facebook page like this (using django but I don't think this causes the problem):

```
document.getElementById('FBshareBtn').onclick = function() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        display: 'popup',
        href: '{{ site_url }}{{ request.get_full_path }}',
    }, function(response){});
};
```

Everything works as normal. Sharing pop up window opens up and I choose to post to a page that I manage as the administrator of that page.

Content is indeed shown to my facebook page after a while, but only me can see it. Users that have liked/are following the page cannot see it.

They can see content created from inside my facebook page, though.

For some reason, content shared from another website is "hidden".

PS: I haven't purchased a domain, yet, for my website so I am using numerical IP (e.g. 'http://188.55.66.28:8008/articles/view/1') when I am sharing.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If posted stuff is only visible to you, go to "App Review" in your App settings and make sure the checkbox for live is set to the correct status:

> ON - Your app is currently live and available to the public.

Comment: Thanks. This works. But why? I do have an app, that I don't indent to use. What if I delete the app?. Does that mean that I won't be able to share? I do set "AppId" on my FB.init, however. Is it needed?

Comment: yes, it is needed, of course. this is useful for testing. you can even do that on a live page now.